# Clickable images in colorbox

Tags: jquery, drupal, colorbox

I have read all the threads that seemed to match my question as was unable to locate a solution that helped. Using Drupal 7, and theme with color box that opening images from 4 recent posts.

The home page has a recent section and there are 4 thumbs. When any of these thumbs are clicked on to open, color box appears and when you click on the first image, it changes to the second image, etc, etc then back to number one.

I would like these individual images, in color box, to be clickable to their own Galleries. Colorbox its self has small arrows (lower left corner) to show the next of 4 images anyway.

Any thoughts on how I can do this will be appreciated. So far I have been reading and trying to two days and have had no luck finding a fix.

Thanks

S

Comment: Hi Steve welcome to stack overflow, you need to include some code in your question in order for us to be able to help you.  [Please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: +1 for @Pete's advice. Please add a live example of your problem, ie. using http://jsbin.com/

Comment: Well I would if I knew where to start. Thanks anyway.